# How do I show 'Names and Pictures' by default in Messages.app?

Tags: macos, messages

I am running the latest Mavericks version, 10.9.2.

Comment: Duplicate question. See answer at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131477/set-messages-app-to-show-names-and-pictures-by-default-for-all-conversations?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for this in the View menu.

[image: View > Messages > Show Names And Pictures]

It should carry over to every conversation.

Comment: The problem seems to be that Messages.app does not save this as the default anymore even after you select it. So you have to select it every time you restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

This option doesn't exist in my messages app.  I only see initials for contacts, sometimes pictures.  How can I revert?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: yeah its changed

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this question earlier today. Figured out that I had to just drag the scroll bar between the conversation pane on the right and the pane on the left that shows the contacts over to the right and then the names showed up. That menu does not appear on my MacBook Air running 10.11.2 or my iMac running 10.11.1.

Seems easier once you know you can just drag it over. That menu was hidden.

Hope this helps.

Comment: this doesnt work im afraid