# Set Messages app to show Names and Pictures by default for all conversations

Tags: macos, messages

I know I can set show names and pictures for conversations. How do I set this as default for all conversations? I set this and then exit messages and re-open it and it is back to only showing the pictures. I tried to delete the plist files from ~/Library/Preferences for iChat.

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Mine when checked does the same.

So I set it again and I also changed the **Show As Balloons** to **Show As boxes**. Quit and re opened. This stuck.

I then Change back to **Show As Balloons**  Quit and re opened. Both settings stuck.

Tested on two Macs. Same thing

---

Further investigation which I think proves it is a bug

The **show names and pictures** or what ever you set in the app is actually being written out to the plist file.

The Dictionary **SOTranscriptSettingsDefaultIMChatSettingsPreferences**
  that holds this preference **participantDisplay** changes from number value 0 to 1 or 2.

The problem is the original default in the Dictionary **SOTranscriptSettingsDefaultIMChatSettingsPreferences**
is to only have the **participantDisplay** entry.

When you also change the  **Show As Balloons** setting to something else like boxes a new entry  **transcriptStyleID** is added to the Dictionary **SOTranscriptSettingsDefaultIMChatSettingsPreferences**. Which will have the string value of for example *com.apple.iChat.Styles.Balloons*.

Once both entries exist then the setting **participantDisplay** is actually actioned.

I used Defaults delete,write to remove and replace these settings and the results are consistent.

Comment: I have filed a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Apple have advised me this is fixed in 10.10. Although I cannot specify here yet (pre public release). It has "in a way been" fixed in 10.10

Comment: still a big problem today

Comment: can you provide detail instructions?